# Bing Maps private TileSource

Tags: authentication, bing-maps, basic-authentication

I'm using Bing Maps with an extra TileSource. All works well, except that I need to make the tiles private, as they're different for each user. Authentication/Authorization is provided via HttpBasicAuth

I don't see any way to send an Authorization header with the tiles without messing with the Bing library.

What are my options?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is to send the Authorization header in the URL. As long as the channel is secure (HTTPS), I think that could work, though it's not elegant.